# Where to find traditional cuica in Rio de Janeiro?

Tags: culture, brazil, music

I have a friend traveling in Brazil. He is a fan of Brazilian music, as I am, and asked me if I knew where to find traditional "cuica" to buy. Unfortunatly I don't but maybe someone around knows.

[image: cuica]

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of musical instruments shops at [Rua da Carioca](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/R.+da+Carioca+-+Centro,+Rio+de+Janeiro+-+RJ,+20050-020,+Brazil/@-22.9066408,-43.1803123,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x997f60b4f67263:0xefbde94c19437c91), downtown. You can find a cuíca there. Also, downtown is certainly a destination for tourists, so he's probably going there anyway.

For example, *Casa Oliveira de Música* is located at Rua da Carioca and in [their website](http://www.casaoliveirademusica.com.br) they claim to sell cuícas among many other percussion instruments.